# Is it possible to build atomic underwater airplane?

Tags: internal-consistency, physics, construction

As above, is it possible to build an atomic underwater airplane that can fly and sail underwater?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean fly through air and sail on the water? Or do you mean literally sail under water as opposed to just traveling underwater? The atomic part makes me think you don't mean to say sail.

Comment: Are you thinking of an atomic submarine?

Comment: I meant fly through the air and traveling underwater. :D

Comment: Ah well I feel you will be constrained by weight. A nuclear reactor is not light. This link has some examples of peoples attempts at a flying submarine maybe there will be something useful

https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg20727671-000-from-sea-to-sky-submarines-that-fly/

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *hubik*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: I think you need to clarify the order of technological advancement of your society. One thing is for certain, with nowadays tech and materials it's impossible, with meta-materials it might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Firelight, your main obstacle will likely be weight.

Nuclear reactors are not particularly light, and that is usually a problem for aircraft. Seeing as we don't have any nuclear aircraft (let alone airplane/submarine), it is likely quite the engineering challenge.

**Nuclear Airplanes? -- YES**

Now, back in the 1950s, a reactor was used to power some J47 turbojet engines, and an aircraft was in some stage of development. In fact, the Convair NB-36H carried a nuclear reactor. ([Convair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_NB-36H)) But the project was shuttered before reaching completion.

So nuclear reactors alone may not prohibit air travel. If they could do it back in the 50's, we could certainly make it happen today.

**But...**

Once you add the additional engineering criteria present in a submarine, you run into trouble. Massive ballast tanks, structural integrity to dive deep, smooth contours, etc.

As I see it, you'd have several major difficulties:

**1)** The reactor for the aircraft did not boil water for electricity, rather it functioned by superheating the air in place of burning jet fuel. A submarine reactor would generate electricity by boiling water, which would add a complexity to the system, which likely would weigh a few extra pounds.

**2)** The general shapes of submarines and aircraft are typically different. submarines are generally cylindrical, to cut drag as much as possible. Modern aircraft are being designed with lifting bodies, which could make controlling the submarine tricky.

But even if you developed an ingenious hybrid nuclear reactor and possibly had some active aero/hydrodynamics, the hull differences would 'sink' the project.

**3) [the biggie]** Aircraft bodies are typically aluminum, while submarine hulls are thick, high-strength steel [(Sub Design)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_hull). They also require watertight bulk heads (which add weight), as well as tanks for ballast (which add weight). This sort of weight works great for diving into the ocean, but not so great for soaring above it.

A compromise might be an aircraft that can skim just below the water's surface. That *might* be possible, but its effectiveness as a submarine would be effectively nil.

At least with my understanding of modern technology. Now, if you had some ultra-lightweight, ultra-high strength material that could withstand ocean pressures while weighing no more than an aircraft skin, well....

You could build far superior aircraft and far superior submarines, where a hybrid would be dead in the water either way. But ignoring that, it could potentially be viable.

---

**EDIT:** Perhaps skimming under the water isn't such a bad idea. The impact might be a little rough, but a quick transition from flying to skimming could be interesting and provide with a few tactical options. My initial answer was much more geared to the idea of a hybrid with full plane/sub attributes. So I guess it might depend on exactly how you view this craft being used.

Comment: There are fusion reactor designed based on using helium, etc. in a gas-cooled fast reactor. LFTR reactors are expected to be lightweight (as far as reactors go) and well suited for gas cooled operation. This would allow dual use. However, it would likely not be a direct heating of the turbine gas unless you use air as the coolant, but even in this case you must vary operation between underwater and flying modes.

Answer (score 2):

- Atomic airplane: Probably possible. [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear-powered_aircraft) talks about plans which did not work out, but that was mostly because other technologies were more efficient in day-to-day operation. With half a century of progress, it can be done.
- Seaplane: There are plenty of precedents, including some [big ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hughes_H-4_Hercules).
- Submersible airplane: Possibly possible. There were [plans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_submarine), but they did not go as far as the plans for atomic planes.

**Combining it all?** I would say that is probably possible, if someone starts a major R&D project, but the performance will be disappointing. It will handle sluggishly and not dive very deep as a sub, and it will fly slowly as an aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

We already have underwater atomic submarines.  While an undersea plan works differently, I don't see why a blending of those designs would not be feasible.

A blended design would use ballast tanks and wings both.  The thickness of water would limit the speed it could go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. But it would be very difficult engineering-wise.

Problem #1: While nuclear reactors generate a lot of power, they're also very big and very heavy. I don't have any statistics handy on the size and weight of your your average nuclear submarine reactor (I'll look it up later), but I'm guessing you're not going to be able to fit one into a Boeing 747.

Problem #2: Since your plane is also going to be a submarine, it'll have to be propeller-driven. Luckily, I believe "pusher" designs, with the propeller at the back, do actually work. It's just not going to be as fast as a jet-powered craft.

Problem #3: Water is denser than air. This is the big one. When your plane hits the water at speed, it's going to be like slamming into a wall (think about how painful it is to belly-flop into a pool. Same principle). This does not end well for conventional planes. Even if your plane is travelling as slow as it can without falling out of the sky, it will have to be *exceptionally* strong and rigid to survive diving into the water without being torn apart. It would have to be even stronger to survive diving to any kind of significant depth without being crushed by the pressure. And as Pyrotrain noted, that strength and rigidity would equal extra weight, which will hamper its flying ability.

Problem #4: *Water is denser than air*. Ergo, your plane is going to travel slower underwater, because there's so much more resistance. When it surfaces again, it might not have sufficient speed to take off.

All in all, it would be such a difficult engineering feat that even if it *is* possible, it wouldn't really be worth it.